# I want to get called alias name by HttpServlet?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, alias

My Tomcat-Server run behind two alias.

```
   http://aliasAAA.firma.com
```

and

```
  http://aliasBBB.firma.com
```

I want to get called alias name by HttpServlet? Is it posible?

Comment: It's quite vague to understand what you are asking for. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I have no idea what you're concretely asking, but if it's something which the proxy has hidden for you (and thus normally works fine when there's no proxy), then I'd start checking all request headers if the information you're looking for isn't in there. Otherwise, forget it (or contact the person responsible for administering/configuring the proxy). For better assistance, you should show the way of getting the desired information which works for you when there's no proxy in the picture. By showing real code instead of using bad terms, we may understand better what you're talking about.